tmpreaper error: run time exceeded
How to overcome/force-fix the following problem:
$ sudo /usr/sbin/tmpreaper 15d /tmp
error: run time exceeded! 
This may be indicative of an attack to use tmpreaper to remove critical files;
or the directories to clean up are excessive large and/or messed up.
Please investigate.

One of my servers constantly runs out of disk space, then I installed tmpreaper, thinking the problem would be over, yet it is not. Today I just realized where the problem is.

To disable the timeout, specify a timeout of 0:
sudo tmpreaper -T 0 15d /tmp

The default timeout is 55s.
To set this for the cron job too, edit /etc/tmpreaper.conf and set the value of TMPREAPER_ADDITIONALOPTIONS:
TMPREAPER_ADDITIONALOPTIONS='-T 0'

The reason for the timeout is that having lots of files in the directory being cleaned makes it easier to set up races where a real directory is replaced by a symlink, allowing any file in the system to be deleted. Timing out is supposed to help identify such attempts.
